# How to submit form with JavaScript using datalist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

This is working form with select, but how to make it work same but in form?

```
<select id="destination" name="destination" onchange="navigate(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">

<option value="">Select country</option>
<option value="afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="albania">Albania</option>
<option value="algeria">Algeria</option>
<option value="andorra">Andorra</option>
<option value="angola">Angola</option>
```

Script.js

```
 function navigate(destination) 

{

   if (destination != "")

    location.href = destination + ".php"; 

}
```

It is there anyway make it work with "datalist"?

```
<datalist id="countries" >
        <option value="Afghanistan">
        <option value="Albania">
        <option value="United Kingdom">
        <option value="United States">
        <option value="Vanuatu">
        <option value="Vatican City">
        <option value="Yemen">
        <option value="Zambia">
        <option value="Zimbabwe">
    </datalist>
```

Comment: tried this to:
onsubmit="navigate(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)"

Comment: I really couldn't get ur probem..Do you want to attain the value u have selected in your text box.

Comment: @user3741790 Does this help.. http://jsfiddle.net/exunx6v0/

Comment: @user3741790, where did `destination ` came from?

Comment: Thank you all for reply, I just need to open "value"+ ".php" file when submit button pushed.
For example: here is the list which is works fine:
`code`function navigate(destination) 

{

   if (destination != "")

    location.href = destination + ".php"; 

}
`code`

Comment: The datalist is irrelevant. All it does it provide one way for users to put text into the `input type=text` element. What you need to do is assign an `id` to the `input type=text` like I showed you in the answer below, and then to grab the `value` of the `input`, and then to build an URL based on that value. Take another look at my code - I show exactly how to do this.

Comment: :( did exactly how you suggested but it just add ?txtCountry=CountryName at the end of URL, not CountryName.php 
please take a look http://tinyurl.com/o2b8a4r

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar can't see your JS code, can you post it please?

Comment: @TelePuzik I am not sure of your requirement..So check this and let me know http://jsfiddle.net/exunx6v0/1/

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar form is OK but i need when click submit button, page will transfer to URL country_name.php , for example, when select Afghanistan and click submit, it will transfer to afghanistan.php in URL. 
nothingisnecessary already posted code but it transfer to ?txtCountry=CountryName 
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

To get the form value in the `onsubmit` handler via JavaScript you can assign `id` to the `input` element, and then programatically read its `value`.

```js
function myFunction() {

  // 1. use the id 'txtCountry' to get reference to the INPUT element
  // Note: you need to edit your HTML to assign the id 'txtCountry' (see sample HTML below)
  var txtCountry = document.getElementById('txtCountry');

  // 2. assign the value (text) in the INPUT element to a variable called 'destination'
  var destination = txtCountry.value;

  // 3. redirect to an URL based on the value from step 2
  var url = destination + ".php";
  
  alert("You are about to redirect to\n\n" + url);
  location.href = url;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="myFunction()">
  Enter country:
  <input type="text" id="txtCountry" name="txtCountry" list="countries">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<datalist id="countries">
  <option value="Afghanistan">
    <option value="Albania">
      <option value="United Kingdom">
        <option value="United States">
          <option value="Vanuatu">
            <option value="Vatican City">
              <option value="Yemen">
                <option value="Zambia">
                  <option value="Zimbabwe">
</datalist>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works, but what should I add, to make it submitted as a site.com/Albania.php when Albania is selected?

I have this function working in Select element, but need it in form

Comment: Same way you had it, just append the url (see updated answer). Since you are using a `input / datalist` instead of `select` be careful if not using a white list of countries, otherwise any input the user enters may go to a non-existent url and get 404 not found (depending on how you have configured your web app).

Comment: It doesnt work with datalist :( removed confirm code from code you provided and it is just go to site.com/test.html?txtCountry=Afghanistan not site.com/Afghanistan.php

Comment: You need to show your code. You didn't show us what `destination` means. Please edit your question and repost your code after applying my suggested changes, otherwise I can not help you further.